# Error "expression is not assignable" on timerBar.bounds.size.width assignment

Tags: ios

I'm trying to create a timerbar, but i'm getting an error "Expression is not assignable" on `timerBar.bounds.size.width = 0`

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];  

timerBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH , 5)];
timerBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:timerBar];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    timerBar.bounds.size.width = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can the value not be assigned?

Comment: I have added an actual question and cleaned up your layout. Please do that yourself next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't direct set Bounds width to zero!

```
CGFloat width = 0;
timerBar.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width , 5)
```